# How do I expand a file system to fill a partition?

Tags: linux, filesystems, parted, partition-table

As shown in the picture below, I've created partitions on two 32GB devices: an SD-card, and a flash usb stick.

I intended to create file systems using the entire partition in each case, yet somehow I've failed:

On **sdb**, **/dev/sdb1** is **29.8GB**, yet the file system is only **1023MB**.

The SD card, **mmcblk0p2**, is **30GB**, but /dev/mmcblk0p2 is only **1.9GB**.

How can I rectify this?

[image]

Comment: What filesystem type is on that partition?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If the partition is larger than the filesystem, you can use [resize2fs](http://linux.die.net/man/8/resize2fs) to expand it:

> If size parameter is not specified, it will default to the size of the partition.

So it'd just be

```
[#]> resize2fs /dev/sdb1
```

Comment: Thanks, Xiong! I tried this, and it worked for the SD-card file system, but not for the USB drive. "resize2fs: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/sdb1 Couldn't find valid filesystem superblock." Any thoughts?

Comment: What filesystem is /dev/sdb1?  Can you run `df -T`?

Comment: Looks like FAT (vfat).

Comment: resize2fs only works on ext-family filesystems.  I can find some reports of [fatresize](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man1/fatresize.1.html) and [parted](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-hardware-18/resize-fat32-filesystem-to-fill-partition-using-parted-619334/) working to resize not just the partition, but the filesystem as well, but I haven't tried either of these.